# android can't destroy my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

Destroy app solved! Thanks for help!
Right now activity is destroy but status icon still appear on status bar. Can you help me with remove icon in the same time when app is closing? I suspect onDestroy section problem...

---

I've got a simple app with status bar icon. When Activity start and user press onPause(), status bar icon apper. Click on this icon resuming app but when I'd like do destroy activity I've got an error. Somebody could help mi with this?

```
private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jajko);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butStart);
    miekko = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butMiekko);
    srednio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butSrednio);
    twardo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butTwardo);

    miekko.setOnClickListener(this);
    srednio.setOnClickListener(this);
    twardo.setOnClickListener(this);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Jajko.this, R.raw.alarm);

    showNotification(this);
}


    public static void showNotification(Context context) {
        final Intent result_intent = new Intent(context, Jajko.class);

        result_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);              

        TaskStackBuilder stack_builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stack_builder.addParentStack(Jajko.class);
        stack_builder.addNextIntent(result_intent);


        PendingIntent pending_intent = stack_builder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        builder.setContentIntent(pending_intent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon))
            .setTicker("test")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentInfo("cinfo")
            .setContentText("ctext");
        Notification n = builder.build();
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, n);     
    }

public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        mp.release();
        if (isFinishing()) {
            notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: Could please post your code? At least Jajko.java:252 line? There's something null at that line.

Comment: what is the code in this line Jajko.java:252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case , super.onDestroy must be called to destroy activity due to it's part of android life cycle.

So you can put your code in try/catch and it will work.

```
public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            mp.release();
            if (isFinishing()) {
                notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Right now activity is destroy but status icon still appear on status bar. Can you help me with remove icon in the same time when app is closing? I suspect onDestroy section problem...

Answer (score 0):

You have `NullPointerException` in method:

```
public void onDestroy() {
  mp.release();
if (isFinishing()) {
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
}
super.onDestroy();

}
```

before you invoke `mp.release();` verify that its not `null`

I would write it like:

```
 public void onDestroy() {

  if(mp != null){
      mp.release();
  }

if (isFinishing()) {
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
}
super.onDestroy();

}
```

However the same validation you can put on  `notificationManager` as well.